# Typescript namespace and import node module

Tags: import, typescript, namespaces, visual-studio-code

My typescript project structure is as follows:

/[image]

The file *TableController* looks as follows:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/pg/pg.d.ts" />

//import pg = require("pg"); 

namespace DataAccess {
    export class TableController {
        constructor() { }
    }
}
```

The file *CustomerTable* looks as follows:

```
/// <reference path="TableController.ts" />

namespace DataAccess {
    export class CustomerTable extends TableController {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I uncomment the **import** line in *TableController*, CustomerTable throws an error:

> Cannot find name 'TableController'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `pg` looks like a directory. Do you mean to `import` a file?

Comment: From the manual: Import a module for side-effects only

Though not recommended practice, some modules set up some global state that can be used by other modules. These modules may not have any exports, or the consumer is not interested in any of their exports. To import these modules, use:

import "./my-module.js";

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: pg is a node module (in the folder node_modules).
I do not understand your comment, can you explain what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: I think you have a path problem.

Comment: Please dont comment if you cant answer the question...

Comment: Comments don't require an answer. Anyone can comment. The answer section is for answers. Further, please realize that this site is full of those volunteering their time. Be polite. No one owes you an answer.